# How does MatchEvaluator in Regex.Replace work?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace, matchevaluator

This is the input string `23x * y34x2`. I want to insert `" * "` (star surrounded by whitespaces) after every number followed by letter, and after every letter followed by number. So my output string would look like this: `23 * x * y * 34 * x * 2`.

This is the regex that does the job: `@"\d(?=[a-z])|[a-z](?=\d)"`. This is the function that I wrote that inserts the `" * "`.

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\d(?=[a-z])|[a-z](?=\d)");   
MatchCollection matchC;
matchC = reg.Matches(input);
int ii = 1;
foreach (Match element in matchC)//foreach match I will find the index of that match
{
    input = input.Insert(element.Index + ii, " * ");//since I' am inserting " * " ( 3 characters )
    ii += 3;                                        //I must increment index by 3
}
return input; //return modified input
```

My question how to do same job using .net `MatchEvaluator`? I am new to regex and don't understand good replacing with `MatchEvaluator`. This is the code that I tried to wrote:

```
{
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"\d(?=[a-z])|[a-z](?=\d)");
    MatchEvaluator matchEval = new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceStar);
    input = reg.Replace(input, matchEval);
    return input;
}
public string ReplaceStar( Match match )
{
    //return What??
}
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

A [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator%28VS.71%29.aspx) is a delegate that takes a Match object and returns a string that should be replaced instead of the match. You can also refer to groups from the match. You can rewrite your code as follows:

```
string input = "23x * y34x2";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\d(?=[a-z])|[a-z](?=\d)");
string result = reg.Replace(input, delegate(Match m) {
    return m.Value + " * ";
});
```

To give an example of how this works, the first time the delegate is called, Match parameter will be a match on the string `"3"`. The delegate in this case is defined to return the match itself as a string concatenated with `" * "`. So the first `"3"` is replaced with `"3 * "`.

The process continues in this way, with delegate being called once for each match in the original string.

Comment: I'd like to mention that since the addition of lambda expressions `delegate(Match m) { return m.Value + " * "; }` can be replaced by `(Match m) => return m.Value + " * ";`. Yay progress.

Comment: ^ which can be simplified further as just `(m) => m.Value + "*"`

Comment: ^which can be simplified by omitting the parantheses and using string-interpolation :-) ```m => $"{m.Value}*"```