# How do you use Regular Expressions to replace a particular match (e.g "last" or "second to last")?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, matchevaluator

I am trying to replace a single (last or next-to-last) match in a string. I have my Regular Expression already and it works, but it replaces ALL items, then I have to run back through and replace a single item.

```
Regex.Replace(BaseString, MatchString, ReplacementString)
```

I want to use MatchEvaluator but can't figure out how.

Any help?

Comment: Depending on your usage, you should consider creating a `Regex` instance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MatchEvaluator is simply a delegate. You pass in your function.

In your case, use something like:

```
Regex.Replace(BaseString, MatchString, delegate(Match match)
                    {
                        bool last = match.NextMatch().Index == 0;

                        if (last)
                            return match.Value;
                        else
                            return ReplacementString;
                    }, RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

This code skips the last match. You could also check for next-to-last match in a similar manner.

Also see this question for more information on how to use MatchEvaluator: [How does MatchEvaluator in Regex.Replace work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587866/how-does-matchevaluator-works-c-regex-replace)

Answer (score 4):

This is to replace the last occurance in the string:

```
String testString = "It is a very good day isn't it or is it.Tell me?";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(testString, 
                  "(.*)(it)(.*)$", 
                  "$1THAT$3", 
                   RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

If you can provide when the next to last should be replace, I can edit the answer to include that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The next to last should be the second-to-last match.

If you have haystack string: "Trying to find a particular string." - then the "next to last" would be the "i" in "particular".

Comment: I understood what next to last means, but confused when you say last or next-to-last should be  replaced. Do you mean last two occurances should be replaced?

Comment: Fair enough. No, in "next to last" I just wanted the second to last to be replaced, but not the last. So, in the above Haystrick string: the "i" in "particular" _but not_ the "i" in "string".

Comment: So if the text occurs twice or more then next to last shd be replaced, else the last occurance..Will update the answer...

Comment: If I had known how to do "next to last" in regex, I would have done that, so it would be useful for using regex outside C# (where I can't use the MatchEvaluator delegate function).

Answer (score 0):

find in loop, save the last match position, then replace

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a non for-each option, I want to do it in a more elegant fashion. Your method would definitely work.

Comment: i believe that regex just wasn't designed for loops