# Replace part of a string between the x and x+1 occurrence c#

Tags: c#, string, replace, find-occurrences

My code.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE1(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,)";
//Insert value for the third column(between the 3rd and 4th comma)
Regex rgx = new Regex(@", null"); 
sql = rgx.Replace(sql, ", 'abc'", 3);// this doesn't work
sql = rgx.Replace(sql, ", 'def'", 4);// second insert
```

Desired result

```
sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE1(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (, NULL, NULL, 'abc', 'def', NULL,)";
//Then I'll remove the first and last comma between the VALUES parenthesis.
```

Comment: _"//Then I'll remove the first and last comma"_ Is this part of this or your next question?

Comment: What is the result that you Actually get from that? And at first glance I don't think you can use RegEx in that way (although my knowledge of them is limited)

Comment: @Tim I mentioned that because of the SQL syntax

Answer (score 1):

Use like this;

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE1(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,)";

string nulls = "NULL";
List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(sql, nulls))
{
     indexes.Add(match.Index);
}

sql = sql.Remove(indexes[2], 4).Insert(indexes[2], "'abc'");
Console.WriteLine(sql);
```

Output will be;

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (,NULL, NULL, 'abc', NULL
, NULL,)
```

As an explanation, this will find third `NULL` in your query, then replace itself with `'abc'`.

Here a <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/DRdDUz)</kbd>.

Comment: Good example, BUT... what happens when I want to make the second insert ? After the first insert, the list of indexes don't correspond anymore.

Comment: @Misi You can change indexes in line `sql = sql.Remove(indexes[2], 4).Insert(indexes[2], "'abc'");` But remember, when you insert first `'abc'` indexes available from `0` to `3` since you have 4 `NULL` instead of 5 in your sql.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension method. A modified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186653/c-sharp-indexof-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-string).

```
public static string ReplaceSpecifiedIndex(this string input, string valueToBeReplaced, string replacingvalue, int index)
  {
            input = input.ToLower();
            valueToBeReplaced = valueToBeReplaced.ToLower();
            replacingvalue = replacingvalue.ToLower();
            Match m = Regex.Match(input, "((" + valueToBeReplaced + ").*?){" + index + "}");
            int specificIndex = -1;
            if (m.Success)
                specificIndex = m.Groups[2].Captures[index - 1].Index;

     if (specificIndex > -1)
     {
                string temp = input.Substring(specificIndex, valueToBeReplaced.Length);
                int nextsubstring = specificIndex + valueToBeReplaced.Length;
                input = input.Substring(0, specificIndex) + temp.Replace(valueToBeReplaced, replacingvalue) + input.Substring(nextsubstring);
      }
      return input;
  }
```

and call it like this

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE1(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,)";
sql = sql.ReplaceSpecifiedIndex("null", "abc", 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without regex:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE1(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,)";
int indexOfvalues = sql.IndexOf("VALUES (");
if (indexOfvalues >= 0)
{
    indexOfvalues += "VALUES (".Length;
    int endIndexOfvalues = sql.IndexOf(")", indexOfvalues);
    if (endIndexOfvalues >= 0)
    {
        string sqlValues = sql.Substring(indexOfvalues, endIndexOfvalues - indexOfvalues);
        string[] values = sqlValues.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if(values.Length >= 3)
            values[2] = "'abc'";
        string newValues = string.Join(",", values);
        sql = string.Format("{0}{1})", sql.Substring(0, indexOfvalues), newValues.Trim());
    }
}
```

Result:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'abc', NULL, NULL)
```

or with `String.Split` shorter and more readable (possibly a little bit more dangerous):

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE1(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,)";
string[] tokens = sql.Split(new[] { "VALUES" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
if (tokens.Length == 2)
{
    string[] values = tokens[1].Trim('(', ')', ',', ' ').Split(',');
    if (values.Length >= 3)
        values[2] = "'abc'";
    string newValues = string.Join(",", values);
    sql = string.Format("{0} VALUES ({1})", tokens[0], newValues);
}

// same result
```

Answer (score 0):

MatchEvaluator is simply a delegate. You pass in your function.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4566891/431471

Answer (score 0):

[You really could use the regular expression /((s).*?){n}/ to search for n-th occurrence of substring s.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186653/c-sharp-indexof-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-string/187394#187394)

And regarding `//Then I'll remove the first and last comma.`

```
sql = sql.Replace("(,", "(").Replace(",)", ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've edited the `StrExtract` function from the the [VFP Toolkit for .NET](http://foxcentral.net/microsoft/vfptoolkitnet.htm) and got a new function that I named `StrReplace`.

```
public static string StrReplace(string cSearchExpression, string replacement, string cBeginDelim, string cEndDelim, int nBeginOccurence)
    {
        string cstring = cSearchExpression;
        string cb = cBeginDelim;
        string ce = cEndDelim;

        if (cSearchExpression.Contains(cBeginDelim) == false && cSearchExpression.Contains(cEndDelim) == false)
        {
            return cstring;
        }

        //Lookup the position in the string
        int nbpos = At(cb, cstring, nBeginOccurence) + cb.Length - 1;
        int nepos = cstring.IndexOf(ce, nbpos + 1);

        //Reaplce the part of the string if we get it right
        if (nepos > nbpos)
        {
            cstring = cstring.Remove(nbpos, nepos - nbpos).Insert(nbpos, replacement);
        }
        return cstring;
    }
```

`At` function can be found in the toolkit.

```
sql = strings.StrReplace(sql , " abc", ",", ",", 3);
sql = strings.StrReplace(sql , " def", ",", ",", 4);
```