# Incremental character replacement using regex

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

Hello I have a string like following

```
Some text here -   
~XY*901*000000001~MLC*~XY*901*000000005~MLC*~XY*901*0000000010~MLC* 
Some text here
```

I want to have it like -

```
Some text here 
~XY*901*000000001~MLC*~XY*901*000000002~MLC*~XY*901*000000003~MLC* 
Some text here
```

Explanation: everything in between `~XY*901*` and `~MLC*` should be incremented by one starting from 1.

How to achieve it using Regex Match Evaluator?

Comment: I wonder how you increment these numbers if you have `5` that becomes `2` and `10` that becomes `3`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew We can using C# match evaluators, It's just that I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Downvoters please leave a comment for Downvotes. It's ridiculous when my issue is clearly stated, I don't know how to explain it better than this

Comment: The question might a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587866/how-does-matchevaluator-in-regex-replace-work

Comment: No, It's not, Still I am working on it, will post as answer in case I succeed

Comment: Then why ask a question in the first place? Either add the current code you need help with, or remove the off-topic question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It will take me time to get the solution, how can I post it right now, When I don't have the solution then why shall I not post it here?

Comment: he was asking you to post the code you have that is not working, not to post the solution.

Comment: @Maslow, I resolved it completely and was about to post answer but LukStorms had posted the below answer by that time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of lambada. Erhm, I mean lambda.

```
var input = @"Some text here -
~XY*901*000000001~MLC*~XY*901*000000005~MLC*~XY*901*0000000010~MLC*
More text here";

var reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(~XY\*901\*)[0-9]+(~MLC\*)");

int i = 1;
var result = reg.Replace(input, m => m.Groups[1] + i++.ToString("D9") + m.Groups[2]);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The regex Replace loops through the matches of the regular expression.
While increasing the integer.

Output:

```
Some text here -
~XY*901*000000001~MLC*~XY*901*000000002~MLC*~XY*901*000000003~MLC*
More text here
```

Comment: You rock buddy, When I was about to post my own answer  just got yours thanks