# how to add whitespace to separate merged words with punctuation mark if it is between and keep it with whitespace

Tags: c#, regex, string, text, punctuation

I need add white space if my input string, looks like this:

**"hello,world"**

to pass it to write in text document like this:

**"hello, world"** with white-space and keep the punctuation mark at the place.

In other words I need to add one white-space after punctuation mark, if next word is merged with the previous word punctuation marks. And I need it for all, comma, dot, exclamation mark and dash.

So I'm not sure, if I can use this:

```
string input = "hello,world,world,world";

string pattern = @",(\S)";
string substitution = @",  ";

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
```

but in result it cuts first character of word after punctuation mark:

```
hello,  orld,  orld,  orld
```

and desired result should be:

```
"hello, world, world, world"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Regex.Replace` overload which gets a `MatchEvaluator` delegate:

```
string input = "hello!world.world-world";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[\,\.\-\!]", (m) => m + " ");

// hello! world. world- world
```

For more about the `MatchEvaluator` see: [How does MatchEvaluator in Regex.Replace work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587866/6400526)

Comment: Hello, for each symbol separately?

Comment: @mickbt - failed to understand what you want to do that for all the different symbols. See update