# .Net Regex - trying to locate a one liner to convert the case of fully qualified server names

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Trying to answer myself an academic exercise here.

Is there a method using Regular Expressions (.net syntax, so see the caveat below) that I can convert fully qualified server name to a combo upper and lower case string (server name is *UPPER* case, domain name(s) in *lower* case).

e.g.

- db01.local => DB01.local
- DB02.TEST.LOCAL => DB02.test.local
- db03.LOCAL = > DB03.local

I've been playing around with the RE and so far have `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.(.+)` as the pattern, but I'm struggling how to do this in a simple one liner.

My initial tests had me fritzing with `Matches` and getting a returned list, but that feels fugly to me because I then need to check the number of matches, do casting and `ToUpper()` \ `ToLower()` operations etc. and, yeah, well...

**Caveat**: If I wasn't using .NET then I think I should be able to do something simple like use `\U${1}.\L${2}` as my replacement string, but it doesn't look like .NET supports that syntax.

Comment: So your main problem is finding out [how to use a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587866/how-does-matchevaluator-in-regex-replace-work)?

Comment: I'll be honest and say "dunno". As I say, using non .Net regex syntax it seems like I should be able to simply use the substitution pattern I gave in my question and then I'm done. I'm at a total loss on how to do it in .Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the 'Possible duplicate of' link  this is what I ended up with:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.(.+)");
foreach (var i in _knownServers)
   clean.Add(re.Replace(i, m => $"{m.Groups[1].ToString().ToUpper()}.{m.Groups[2].ToString().ToLower()}"));
```